Listagg returns a null record when no result found
Here's my query :
SELECT  
    MAX(g.name) AS good_name,
    MAX(cp.goods_id) as c5good_id,
    LISTAGG(CASE 
                WHEN inf.id IS NULL 
                    THEN cp.catalogues_properties_description_id 
                    ELSE inf.name 
            END ,'-' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) information, 
    LISTAGG(attr.name, '-' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) attributes
FROM
    goods_cp cp 
LEFT JOIN 
    catalogues_properties attr ON cp.catalogues_properties_id=attr.id
LEFT JOIN 
    catalogues_properties inf ON cp.catalogues_properties_description_id = TRIM(to_char(inf.id))
JOIN
    goods g ON g.id = cp.goods_id
WHERE
    cp.goods_id = 123456  ---no data found for this id

The id that I used in my WHERE clause is invalid, and the query must return no rows, but when I use LISTAGG or any aggregation function, it will return 1 null row.
Why is that happening?

It has nothing to do with LISTAGG() analytic function. When selecting
aggregations Where condition with no matching rows will not result with no rows selected - Having clause will. Here is how it looks and it is the same without LISTAGG()...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl AS
    ( Select 1 "A_NUMBER", 'A' "A_LETTER" From Dual Union All
      Select 2 "A_NUMBER", 'B' "A_LETTER" From Dual 
    )


aggregation with NO WHERE clause and NO HAVING clause

--  1. no Where condition and no Having condition 
Select    Max(A_NUMBER) "MAX_NUMBER", 
          Max(A_LETTER) "MAX_LETTER", 
          ListAgg(A_LETTER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By A_LETTER) "LETTERS"
From tbl
/*
MAX_NUMBER MAX_LETTER LETTERS
---------- ---------- -----------
         2 B          A, B          */


aggregation with WHERE clause excluding all (From) rows (like in your question)

--  2. where condition excluding all rows 
Select    Max(A_NUMBER) "MAX_NUMBER", 
          Max(A_LETTER) "MAX_LETTER", 
          ListAgg(A_LETTER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By A_LETTER) "LETTERS"
From tbl
Where     A_NUMBER = 0
/*     R e s u l t :      (1 row with nulls)
MAX_NUMBER MAX_LETTER LETTERS
---------- ---------- -----------
Null       Null       Null         */



aggregation with HAVING clause excluding all rows

--  3. having condition excluding all (aggregated) rows 
Select    Max(A_NUMBER) "MAX_NUMBER", 
          Max(A_LETTER) "MAX_LETTER", 
          ListAgg(A_LETTER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By A_LETTER) "LETTERS"
From tbl
Having    Max(A_NUMBER) = 0
/*    R e s u l t :
no rows selected   */

To get no rows in case like in the question you should probably have both the WHERE and the HAVING clause like below.
Select    Max(A_NUMBER) "MAX_NUMBER", 
          Max(A_LETTER) "MAX_LETTER", 
          ListAgg(A_LETTER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By A_LETTER) "LETTERS"
From tbl
Where     A_NUMBER = 0
Having    Count(*) != 0


That's how is works: aggregate functions returns NULL when no rows are selected, except COUNT() returning 0.

If you use aggregation functions (MAX, SUM, LISTAGG, etc.) without including a GROUP BY clause then the query will always output a single row as it works over the entire results set.
If you include a GROUP BY clause then the query will return one row per group provided there is a set of input rows for that group.
Therefore, if you want to have zero rows output when there are zero rows of input, add a GROUP BY clause:
SELECT MAX(g.name) AS good_name,
       cp.goods_id AS c5good_id,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE 
         WHEN inf.id IS NULL 
         THEN cp.catalogues_properties_description_id 
         ELSE inf.name 
         END ,
         '-' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE
       ) AS information, 
       LISTAGG(
         attr.name,
         '-' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE
       ) AS attributes
FROM   goods_cp cp 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN catalogues_properties attr
       ON cp.catalogues_properties_id=attr.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN catalogues_properties inf
       ON cp.catalogues_properties_description_id = TRIM(to_char(inf.id))
       INNER JOIN goods g
       ON g.id = cp.goods_id
WHERE  cp.goods_id = 123456 
GROUP BY cp.goods_id

